# How to set response headers for HTML pages only on MVC 3 and IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, cache-control

Basically what I'm trying to do is set response headers on all HTML pages to prevent caching, but I want the other resources (JS, CSS, images, etc) to be cacheable.

I looked into doing this in IIS but I only found a global setting and the headers get applied to all resources... also on MVC I found that I can set that on controller actions, but I couldn't find how to set that for .cshtml pages.

As you can see I'm fairly new to MVC.

**Does Anyone have a pointer on how can I accomplish that?**

Thank you!

Eduardo